# Cognito OIDC - Customise user groups in pre-token lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have an OIDC integration on cognito, its using the OIDC code flow where a code is exchanged for a token. I link the OIDC integration to a cognito client, where I then use amplify federated sign in. The login works and I am retuned a valid access token.

My backend and frontend application are using user groups as permissions, so endpoint access/webpage access are controlled by the presence of user groups in the token. The first time a user signs in via OIDC, my backend adds the user to the relevant user groups.

I then have the below code in the pre-token lambda to add groups on the first sign in. The lambda also calls my backend which adds the user to the groups, and this occurs successfully. However on the first and subsequent sigins via OIDC, the access token has no user groups. The code below will work for modifying the user groups of non-oidc tokens.

My question is this: Is it not possible to modify user groups in OIDC tokens? Or is my permission system at fault, and role based would solve the issue?

```
const userGroups = event.request.userAttributes['cognito:groups'] || [];
event.response = {
    claimsAndScopeOverrideDetails: {
        groupOverrideDetails: {
            groupsToOverride: [...userGroups, 'some-group'],
        },
    },
}
```

Please note I have tried multiple variations of the above, and this works for non-oidc access tokens - but not oidc tokens.

On the cogntio trigger I am using V2_0 (Basic features + access token customization) as the trigger event version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the openid parameter from my scopes in the oidc configuration on both amplify and aws. This fixed the issue!

Comment: For clarity, the 3 token types in cognito are the `id_token`, `access_token`, and `refresh_token`. You should be using the `access_token` to authorize against your APIs (user authorization). The `id_token` represents identity (authentication). Until recently, you could not modify an access token in a lambda trigger so some older resources will muddy the waters between those two and use the `id_token` for authorization. Given the feature is now supported, try to maintain that separation.